# Wavelet expansion of given function (as opposed to DWT of given data)

Tags: wavelet-analysis

To illustrate, say I take the following function (the reason for the square root will be apparent soon)

```
dist = NormalDistribution[0.5,0.1];
f[x_] := Sqrt[PDF[dist,x]];
```

Then I can grab the Haar wavelet to calculate coefficients like

```
data = Table[Evaluate@f[x], {x,0,1,1/31}]; (* 32 equally spaced points *)
dwt = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data, HaarWavelet[], 5];
```

If I then take squares of coefficients, because of

$$
\sum _{j=J_o}^{J_1} \sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \psi _{j,k}^2+\sum _{z\in \mathbb{Z}} \varphi _{J_0,k}^2\simeq \int f^2 (x) \, dx = \left\| f\right\| ^2
$$

I should get $\simeq 1.0$ as $f$ is, in this case, the square root of a probability density function. And it kind-of works; to wit:

```
Total[Flatten[Last[#] & /@ dwt[Automatic]]^2]/31
```

returns 1.0 (`dwt[Automatic]` gives you the coefficients for the inverse transform only; see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteWaveletTransform.html)). This should be very close to `NIntegrate[Evaluate@f[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}]`, which is *0.999999*.

However, note that "/31"! Where did that come from? This is: that `1/31` does not appear in the Parseval's identity but it is needed for the calculation to work (!)

And if I change `HaarWavelet[]` by `DaubechiesWavelet[]`, say, then this *data sampling* no longer works.

I am even taking care of the fact that the Daubechies family has bigger support and for that I am using the following function to determine the number of points required as:

```
dataSize[wave_, 1] := 
 Length[WaveletFilterCoefficients[wave, "PrimalLowpass"]];
dataSize[wave_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
 2 dataSize[wave, n - 1] - 
  Length[WaveletFilterCoefficients[wave, "PrimalLowpass"]] + 2;
```

What I am doing wrong?

(*Why this?* You may ask. For example, one could use wavelet expansions to calculate the norm (in Hilbert space) between two functions, or a function and some other approximation; instead of attempting `NIntegrate`. By the way, I am actually interested in dimensions greater than 1)

**Note:** I am only interested in *orthogonal* wavelets; Parseval's formula should be just ok as far as I know.

**UPDATE**

I modified `dist` to `NormalDistribution[0.5,0.5]`. In this case, one needs a longer interval `{x,-2,3}` to effectively cover $f$. In this case, the squared coefficients are added like **5**`Total[Flatten[Last[#] & /@ dwt[Automatic]]^2]/31` (note the factor 5.)

This points me to the fact that the $x_i$ sample points are usually considered as in the `[0,1]` interval (if I remember correctly), therefore the final answer needs to be *rescaled* by 5. Still... work in progress.

Comment: You show the code `Total[Flatten[Last[#] & /@ dwt[Automatic]]^2]/31` and then go on to say "note that `/31`! Where did that come from?" Is it not there because you typed it in? If not, where did the whole expression come from? I note `1/31` is the table iteration step you used in an earlier line of code.

Comment: Sorry @m_goldberg, what I meant is that that `1/31` does not appear in the Parseval's identity I mentioned, but I had to put it to make the identity work. And unfortunately it is not as simple as the iteration step, as I used wavelets with bigger support and I was not able to find such _correction factor_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue and the reason.

First, the reason for that 1/31. As explained in documentation for [`DiscreteWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteWaveletTransform.html) (see "Properties & Relations")

```
The energy norm is conserved for orthogonal wavelet families:
In[1]:= data = RandomReal[1, {100}];
In[2]:= dwt = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data, Padding -> 0.];
In[3]:= Norm[data] == Norm[Flatten[Last /@ dwt[Automatic]]]
Out[3]= True
```

Note that in `In[3]`, `Norm[data]` is $\sqrt{\sum d_i^2}$. Given that $d_i~=~f(x_i)$ is a sampling point for $f$, $\int f^2(x) \delta x$ ~ $\sum f^2(x_i) \Delta x$ = $\sum d_i^2 \Delta x$; as in my case $\Delta x = \frac{1}{31}$ this explains the factor I didn't understand.

The other was an issue calculating

```
Total[Flatten[Last[#] & /@ dwt[Automatic]]^2]/31
```

when the wavelet was not Haar's wavelet. The reference above also solves this. Note that `Padding -> 0.` option. The default padding is periodic, which treats the end points as if they were in a circle, not good in this case. This option therefore ensures the transform does not extend the data as periodic beyond the provided points (maybe my `dataSize` function is incorrect, not sure). With `Padding -> 0.` in `DiscreteWaveletTransform` and using $\Delta x$, it works.

Here another example, with a bigger region of interest, `[-2,3]` and using Daubechies wavelet with n=2.

```
Module[
 {dist, wave, f, data, dwt, level = 7},
 wave = DaubechiesWavelet[2];
 dist = NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.5];
 f[x_] := Sqrt[PDF[dist, x]];
 data = Table[f[x], {x, -2, 3, 5/(2^level - 1)}];
 Print[Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, -2, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["f", FontSlant -> "Italic"]]];
 Print[ListPlot[data, PlotLabel -> "Sampling"]];
 Print["Lenght:", Length[data]];
 Print["Aprox. integral from data: ", 5 Total[data^2 ]/2^level];
 dwt = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data, wave, level, Padding -> 0.];
 Print["NIntegrate: ", NIntegrate[Evaluate@(f[x]^2), {x, -2, 3}]];
 Print["Aprox. integral from coefficients: ", 
  5 Total[Flatten[Last[#] & /@ dwt[Automatic]]^2]/2^level];
 ]
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note in this case $\Delta x$ is $\frac{5}{\text{num_samples}}$ = $\frac{5}{2^{level}}$.